# Find the order of the quotient ring $\mathbb Z[x]/J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $J=\{f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]:6\mid f(0)\}$. Show that $J$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$, but not a prime ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$. Also find the order of the quotient ring $\mathbb Z[x]/J$.

I know that any element of the quotient ring $\mathbb Z[x]/J$ is of the form $g(x)+J$, where $g(x)\in \mathbb Z[x].$ But from here how can we find the order of the ring $\mathbb Z[x]/J$ ?

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $f,g\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  $f$ and $g$ map to the same element of the quotient iff $f-g\in J$.  What does this mean about $f(0)-g(0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $J$ is the ideal $(6,X)$: if $f(X)$ has constant term divisible by $6$ then $f(X)=Xg(X)+6k\in (6,X)$, and conversely. Then the quotient is

$$\frac{\Bbb Z[X]}{(6,X)}\simeq \Bbb Z_6$$
The isomorphism is induced by the map that sends $f(X)=\sum a_i X^i$ to $\overline {f(0)}\in \Bbb Z_6$. Since $\Bbb Z_6$ is not a domain, the ideal is not prime.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_6$ is NOT a domain means ?

Comment: The order of the ring is clear to me..But it is not clear that how it is not prime..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Do you know what it means for a commutative ring to be a domain? An integral domain?

Comment: One could also simply note that $2\times3=6\in J$, but $2,3\notin J$.

Comment: @  Servaes   Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Define the ring homomorphism $\varphi\colon \mathbb Z[x]\rightarrow \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ by $f\mapsto f(0) + 6\mathbb Z$. Show that $\operatorname{Ker}\varphi = J$ and deduce $\mathbb Z[x]/J \cong \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$.